# How to create laravel cache facade based on user specific session

Tags: laravel, redis

I have integrated redis cache driver in laravel. My app is social and music. So the authenticated user can access the app, I have to cache the data based on the logged in user. How can I implement this? Can anyone please help out?

Here is the code that I am using right now. Below is the code that fetches the logged in user's posts based on user id.  In the code below, I am creating a cache tag `tfeedsposts` that will set the post data if the cache is not already set.

Is it the best practice to use the same cache tag for every logged in user?

Because I am thinking the same tag will not work for every logged in user, as the user will have different data, so storing the data in the same cache tag will not show the actual data to the user.

If there is an effective way to achieve this, then please let me know.

```
$cachename = 'tfeeds-offset:'.$this->offset.'-limit:'.$this->limit;
        $cached = Cache::tags(['tfeedsposts'])->has($cachename);
     if ($cached) {
                $posts = Cache::tags(['tfeedsposts'])->get($cachename);
                } else {

                    $posts = Post::whereRaw("visibility_id = 1 and user_id IN($friendsids_string) or visibility_id = 2 and user_id IN($follwingids_string) or visibility_id = 3 and user_id IN($follwingids_string) or visibility_id = 3 and user_id IN($friendsids_string)")->orWhere('user_id', $id)->with(['users_liked','users_viewed','shares', 'user','parentpost', 'comments','comments.user', 'comments.comments_liked', 'comments.replies', 'comments.replies.user', 'comments.replies.comments_liked','users_tagged' ,  'notifications_user'])->latest()->paginate(Setting::get('items_page'));
                    Cache::tags(['tfeedsposts'])->put($cachename, $posts, $this->cachettl);
                }
```

Comment: Welcome Paika! What have you tried so far? Could you share any specific code you use and the exact problem you're having? As it stands, the question seems a bit too broad.

Comment: Use a cache key that includes the user id?

Comment: @Jerodev ok thanks for the reply. but if i have to cache a specific record based on posts id not on logged in user id so what do i need to do?